# retrieving value of select after posting form

Tags: php, html, forms, select, post

The select tag is being generated from the database through PHP echo command.

After I post the form including my select element, I want to be able to retrieve the content (between option tag) as well as the value in the option tag. So if I chose Volvo and submitted the form. I want to retrieve Volvo and 1.

```
<select name='car'>
  <option value='1'>Volvo</option>
  <option value='2>Saab</option>
  <option value='3>Mercede</option>
  <option value='4>Audi</option>
</select>
```

This will only retrieve the value.

```
$_POST['car']
```

how can I retrieve both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get like this

```
<select name='car'>
  <option value='1,Volvo'>Volvo</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$value = explode(",",$_POST['car']);
```

you get

```
$value[0]= 1
$value[1]= Volvo
```

Comment: You can do that, but to validate the input (as you always have to) you need to lookup the id in the database, anyway.

Comment: yes but i tried this many time this the way we can get value+text at a time else we have to define another array according to value...

Answer (score 2):

You can't. But you know that 1 is always Volvo.

Just keep it in an array:

```
$cars = array('Volvo', 'Saab,' 'Mercede', 'Audi');
$car_name = $cars[$_POST['car']];
```

This way you can also generate the select from the array:

```
<select name='car'>
  <? foreach ($cars as $key => $car_name): ?>
    <option value='<?= $key ?>'><?= $car_name ?></option>
  <? endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: the problem is that the select tag is being generated dynamically from php file from the database.

Comment: So lookup the name in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using jQuery to manipulate your submission, you can just modify the `value` attribute to include the same word as the content of the option. You wouldn't be able to submit POST data extracted from the content of the option, though.